# Restful webservice - how to send self referenced objects over network?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I was writing Restful webservices at server and faced this issue. I could not send objects which are having its own reference through REST, so I changed my beans and flattened them but I wonder is it a right way to do it? -If no then how to send self referenced objects over network?

For Example.

```
public Class ABC{

    private ABC parent;
    public String abc;
    .....
}
```

Comment: what technology do you use to implement the service?

Comment: spring restful web services and transferring beans using jaxb marshallar in XML format

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)? If so, and irrespective of whether you are using Spring, you might want to look at the examples of data [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/).

Comment: No. I hvae implemented RESTful web services using spring framework. And converting beans to XML using jaxb2-marshaller.

Comment: If you are working in RESTful terms each resource (akin to an Entity) has a unique identifier. Within the resource you can certainly refer to that identifier and to the client it may end up resolving to itself. Flattening down a resource is not necessary and not advisable either. I should mention that identifiers are often string uuids or integers.